# Why it's important to separate compilation and linking processes in C?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, linker, operating-system, compiler-optimization

I've been programming in C for a while and i wondered why is important to separate this processes (Compile and Linking)?

Can someone explain please?

Comment: Why do you think it is important?

Comment: I see many websites and tutorials are doing this processes separately

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is useful in order to decrease rebuilt time. If you change just one source file - it is often no need to recompile whole project but only one or few files.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably less important these days than it was once.

But there was a time when compiling a project could take literally days - we used to do a "complete build" over a weekend back in the 1980s. Just parsing the source code of a single file was a fairly big deal requiring significant amounts of time and memory, so languages were designed so that their modules (source files) could be processed in isolation.

The result was "object files" - `.obj` (DOS/Windows/VMS) and `.o` (unix) files - which contain the relocatable code, the static data, and the lists of exports (objects we've defined) and the imports (objects we need). The linking stage glues all this together into an executable, or into an archive (`.lib`, `.a`, `.so`, `.dll` files etc) for further inclusion.

Making the expensive compilation task operate in isolation led the way to sophisticated incremental build tools like `make`, which produced a significant increase in programmer productivity - still critical for large C projects, like the Linux kernel.

It also, usefully, means that any language that can be compiled into an object file can be linked together. So, with a little effort, one can link C to Fortran to COBOL to C++ and so on.

Many languages developed since those days have pushed the boundaries of what can be stored in object files. The C++ template system requires special handling, and overloaded methods don't quite fit either as plain `.o` files don't support multiple functions with the same name (see [C++ name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)). Java et al uses a completely different approach, with custom code file formats and a "native code" invocation mechanism that glues onto DLLs and shared object files.

Answer (score 2):

Because, compilation is responsible for transforming the source code of every single source code file to a corresponding object code. That's it. So the compiler doesn't have to care about your external symbols (like the libraries and `extern` variables).

Linking is responsible for finding those references and then producing a single binary as if your project was written as a single source code file. (I also recommend that you should refer to wikipedia [linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) page to know the differnce between static and dynamic linking)

If you happen to use the tool `Make`, you will see that it doesn't recompile every file whenever you invoke `make`, it finds what files have been modified since the last build and then recompiles them only. Then the linking process   is invoked. That is a big time saver when you deal with big projects (e.g. linux kernel).

Answer (score 0):

In practice, it is not important at all. Especially for simpler programs, both steps are performed with one program call such as

```
gcc f1.c f2.c f3.c f4.c -o program
```

which creates the executable `program` from these source files.

But the fact remains that these are separate processes and in some cases it is worth noticing this.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked on systems where it takes two days to compile them. You don't want to make a small change then have to wait 2 days to test.